# Finding density function, plus showing $X \sim F$ where F is cdf of X, $X = F^{-1}(U)$, $U\sim unif(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ has a continuous, strictly increasing cdf $F$. Let $Y = F(X)$. What is the density of $Y$? Then let $U \sim unif(0,1)$ and let $X = F^{-1}(U)$. Show that $X\sim F$.

The first part seems like the density of $Y$ is just the pdf $f(X)$. The wording of the problem is confusing me though.

Comment: What does $X \sim F$ even mean?

Comment: I wish I knew... that's a huge part of why the wording/set up is confusing me so much. It doesn't seem to make sense to say that $X$ is distributed as $F$, a cdf. I was hoping there was another possible interpretation that I was missing.

Comment: The notation $X\sim F$ might be slightly on the lax side but it is completely standard. Your comment sounds as if you had no textbook or lecture notes at your disposal and were trying to rediscover the subject through guesses. Is that so?

Comment: @Did - What does $X \sim F$ even mean in this context?

Comment: ^ That $F$ is the distribution function of $X$, i.e. $\mathbb P(X\leqslant x)=F(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Hint: $X$ is a random variable, $F$ is a CDF, so what do you think $X\sim F$ could mean?

Comment: @Did - Oh, I misread. For some reason I thought it was trying to make a circular argument based on assuming it had the cdf $F$ on the first sentence.

Comment: This is a classical problem. (The answer is used in computer simulation.) To start look at 1197188 on this site (beginning of answer).

Comment: Also, maybe look at 1208396

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $F$ is continuous and monotone increasing, it has an inverse function $F^{-1}$, i.e. for any $t\in\mathbb R$, there is a unique number $F^{-1}(t)$ such that $F^{-1}(F(t)) = t$. Recall that the inverse of a monotone increasing function is also monotone increasing. We have 
$$\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t) = \mathbb P(F(X)\leqslant t). $$
Since $F$ takes values in $[0,1]$, it is clear that $\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t)=0$ for $t\leqslant 0$ and $\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t)=1$ for $t\geqslant 1$. For $t\in(0,1)$ we have
$$\mathbb P(F(X)\leqslant t)=\mathbb P(F^{-1}(F(X))\leqslant F^{-1}(t)) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant F^{-1}(t)) = F(F^{-1}(t)) = t. $$
It follows that 
$$\mathbb P(Y\leqslant t)=t 1_{(0,1)}(t) + 1_{[1,\infty)}(t), $$
and therefore the density $g$ of $Y$ is the derivative of the above:
$$g(y) = 1_{(0,1)}(t). $$
In other words, $Y$ has $\mathcal U(0,1)$ distribution.

For the second part, we have for any $t\in\mathbb R$
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(F^{-1}(U)\leqslant t)\\
&= \mathbb P(F(F^{-1}(U))\leqslant F(t))\\&=\mathbb P(U\leqslant F(t))\\&=\mathbb P(U\leqslant t)\\&=  F(t).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why if F is monotonic increasing and continous, that implies that F has inverse? For example, consider F=1 on all $\mathbb{R}$ which is monotonic (and not stricly) increasing and is continuous, however F has no inverse in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: In this problem, we assumed that $F$ was *strictly* increasing, so $x<y$ implies $F(x)<F(y)$.