# Find a CDF function with the help of a given distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $X$ is a given distribution. for an arbitrary increasing function $F_{Y}$ such that $\lim_{y \to \infty} F_{Y}(y)=1$ and $\lim_{y \to -\infty} F_{Y}(y)=0$, find the function $g$ such that if $Y=g(X)$, then $g$ is the CDF for $Y$.

My idea was to use the claim that is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220205/finding-density-function-plus-showing-x-sim-f-where-f-is-cdf-of-x-x-f?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I couldn't get what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. If $X=0$ then $g(X)=g(0)$ is a constant so you cannot choose $g$ so as to get a non-degenerate distribution.

Comment: It’s correct for non constant random variables i guess.